# C print out the acronym based on user input

Tags: c, linux

I am new to Linux and C programming. I have been trying to study command line coding (using nano editor) and been trying to figure out how to make a program that takes one or more command line arguments and prints out the acronym.

My attempt so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    while(argv[i]!='\0')
    {
      if(argv[i] = ' ')
      {
        i++;
        printf("%c,argv[i+i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is with the `int == 0; for(i == 0; i < argc; i++)` ??

Comment: Use `isupper` in `ctype.h`. For example: `if(isupper(argv[i][0]) ...`.

Comment: also `printf("%c,argv[i+i]);` - `argv[i+1]` refers to a `char[]` not a single character

Comment: argv[i] would evaluate to an address; the "==" operator is a test, not an assignment

Comment: I suggest you rewind one step, and just print the program arguments. When that is done, approach the acronym problem.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[i]` itself is already a string. You should only check its first character and iterate over `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(argv[i][0]))
            printf("%c", argv[i][0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a "mybad" for deletion.

Comment: But still... question says lowercase should be ignored so I would expect to see `isupper`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors with

```
int == 0;                       // syntax error
for(i == 0; i < argc; i++)      // i is not set by a comparison
```

And the code doesn't really do it anyway, please try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char acronym[argc];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if(isupper(argv[i][0])) {
            acronym[index] = argv[i][0];
            index++;
        }
    }
    acronym[index] = '\0';
    printf("The acronym is %s\n", acronym);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
test Three Letter better Acronym
The acronym is TLA
```